# How do you access external Metabase configuration file from Azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, metabase

I'm trying to run Metabase on Azure App Service, I've used the public Docker hub metabase/metabase image.

It runs well, but if i resize the app service, or it shuts down due to inactivity, I lose any configuration settings and have to start from scratch (adding database, mapping fields).

Metabase documentation (https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/operations-guide/running-metabase-on-docker.html#mounting-a-mapped-file-storage-volume) states I should mount a local path inside the container, but how does this relate with a web app?

I tried adding an application setting "MB_DB_FILE=/metabase-data/metabase.db" but this hasn't helped.

Comment: This might be of use: https://blog.tomkerkhove.be/2019/07/25/mounting-volumes-on-azure-web-app-for-containers/

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I added application settings to create the application database in an external mysql db. Now if I ever want to host metabase elsewhere i can just point it at the same place and all dashboards and queries should remain.